# Ask a SQL about " select ... join ... "

Tags: sql, database

There are two tables.

Table A :

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | nameX |
| 2 | nameY |

Table B :

| id | aId | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | Foo |
| 2 | 2 | Bar |

Ask a SQL:

when search 'nameY', get

| A.id | A.name | B.id | B.aId | B.name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | nameY |  |  |  |

when search 'Bar', get

| A.id | A.name | B.id | B.aId | B.name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | nameY | 2 | 2 | Bar |

-

SQL:

```
select * from A 
    left join B on A.id = B.aId 
    where A.name like '%nameY%' or B.name like '%nameY%';
```

But get two rows. I don't need the table B when search 'nameY'.

| A.id | A.name | B.id | B.aId | B.name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | nameY | 1 | 2 | Foo |
| 2 | nameY | 2 | 2 | Bar |

Comment: You didn't ask a question or even post a SQL command. The title mentions JOIN, have you tried using it? What's the problem?

Comment: Question changed.

Comment: can you add/clarify what is the expected output you are trying to get

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a typo? You're joining with `aid` which has the value `2` in both rows. Either the expected results are wrong, the data is wrong or you should join with B.Id

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should join `B` table only when `B` table has searched name.

Add "name condition" to `LEFT JOIN` of `B` table

```
SELECT A.id, A.name, B.id, B.name
FROM A
    LEFT JOIN B ON B.aid = A.id AND B.name LIKE '%search%'
WHERE A.name LIKE '%search%' OR B.name LIKE '%search%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `LEFT JOIN` and condition in `ON` clause as follows:

```
select A.*,
       B.*
  from A 
  left join B on A.id = B.aId and B.name like '%nameY%'
 where A.name like '%nameY%' or B.name like '%nameY%';
```

Comment: This will not "pickup" records where only `B` table has matching value

Answer (score 0):

Check This:

You can use a Case Statement to Compare with the Column Values from the tables.

Also the **CASE** statement also follows Datatype Precedence, So We are using **CAST** Function in this.

By Using ON Clause As **A.ID = B.ID**

```
DECLARE  @T TABLE(ID INT,Name VARCHAR(50))
DECLARE  @T1 TABLE(ID INT,AID INT,Name VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @T values
(1,'nameX'),
(2,'nameY')

INSERT INTO @T1 values
(1  ,2,'Foo'),
(2  ,2,'Bar')

SELECT * FROM @T
SELECT * FROM @T1

DECLARE @Search VARCHAR(100) ='%NAMEY%'

SELECT A.ID,A.NAME,
CASE WHEN A.NAME LIKE @Search THEN '' ELSE CAST(B.ID AS CHAR) END AS ID,  
CASE WHEN A.NAME LIKE @Search THEN '' ELSE CAST(B.AID AS CHAR)END AS AID, 
CASE WHEN A.NAME LIKE @Search THEN '' ELSE B.Name END AS Name 
FROM @T A 
LEFT JOIN @T1 B ON A.ID = B.ID 
WHERE A.NAME LIKE @Search OR B.NAME LIKE @Search
```

By Using ON Clause As **A.ID = B.AID**

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.ID,A.NAME,
CASE WHEN A.NAME LIKE @Search  THEN '' ELSE CAST(B.ID AS CHAR) END AS ID, 
CASE WHEN A.NAME LIKE @Search  THEN '' ELSE CAST(B.AID AS CHAR) END AS AID, 
CASE WHEN A.NAME LIKE @Search THEN '' ELSE B.Name END AS Name 
FROM @T A 
LEFT JOIN @T1 B ON A.ID = B.AID 
WHERE A.NAME LIKE @Search OR B.NAME LIKE @Search
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? What was the *significant* change? It wasn't the `SELECT` clause. Code-only answers are acceptable only if the answer to the question is obvious.

Comment: Plz, Check With the **ON Clause** @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: *Edit your answer and explain how it answers the question*. If someone is so inexperienced they'd mix up the columns how are the going to find what's relevant in this unformatted query?

Comment: Edited @PanagiotisKanavos

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want

```
select a.*, null as b_id, null as b_name
from a
where a.name like ?
union all
select a.*, b.id, b.name
from a join
     b
     on a.id = b.aid
where b.name like ?;
```

The `?` is a parameter placeholder for your search string.  If you are not using parameters, learn how to use them in your environment.  Don't munge query strings with constant values.  It is dangerous.

I see no reason to repeat the `aid` in the result set; it is redundant information.